# Xpath functions not working in playwright

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, web-scraping, playwright

Playwright is not working as expected when i try to use xpath functions.

This is the code that i wrote to scrape the text inside the `<h1>` tag of https://example.org.

```
const pw = require('playwright');

async function fetch(url) {
    var browser = await pw.chromium.launch();
    var context = await browser.newContext();
    var page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    const h1 = await page.$('//h1')
    console.log(await h1.evaluate(h1 => h1.innerHTML, h1));
    await browser.close();
}

fetch('https://example.com')
```

When executed this code works perfectly and displays,

```
Example Domain
```

But if i try to get the text inside the h1 tag using the xpath function `text()` like below,

```
const h1 = await page.$('//h1/text()'); // also tried await page.$('xpath=//h1/text()');
console.log(await h1.evaluate(h1 => h1.textContent, h1));
```

It is throwing,

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'evaluate' of null
```

Am i doing something wrong or doesn't it work with xpath functions.

Comment: I suspect it's because `h1`(in your 2nd example) is already a text node so it doesn't have the property `textContent`. So I would try to evaluate just `h1` and see what happens.

Comment: @JackFleeting I tried and it returned `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Michael said, the purpose of the `$` function is to return a DOM element. If you want to evaluate an XPath expression you could use `document.evaluate` inside an `evaluate` function.

```js
async function fetch(url) {
    var browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
    var context = await browser.newContext();
    var page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    console.log(await page.evaluate(() => 
        document.evaluate('//h1/text()', document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE).stringValue));
    await browser.close();
}

fetch('https://example.com')
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `text()` isn't actually a function. It's an abbreviation for an axis step `child::text()` that selects the text nodes of the containing element.

The XPath expression is working perfectly; it's the invoking application code that's wrong. If your XPath expression returns text nodes, then the application can't access `textContent`, because text nodes don't have a `textContent` property. That's DOM for you...